# looking for a mechanism for semaphore interlocks?

Tags: concurrency, semaphore

I have two semaphores each with size 10. The two semaphores are mutually exclusive, such that:

Initially the two semaphores are empty. If one of the semaphore has content, it blocks the other semaphore so that it cannot be filled with content. It unblocks the other semaphore only when the original semaphore is emptied. and the process continues.

In a programming sense, if one semaphore has content, the the other semaphore is blocked by the kernel. How would I go about implement such lock?

Comment: Semaphore is explained as a resource counter. You want such a weird resource that when it is present, other resource cannot be added to the pool. You better explain your task without semaphores, only with terms like resource or messages.

Answer (score 0):

May be define a class like this and use an additional `Pairing` Boolean

```
 class semaphore

{
            int value;
            Boolean Locked;
            Boolean Paired;


        voidsetvalue(int val)
        {
           if(Paired==true)
           {
           Locked=true
           }

           if(locked==false)
           {
           value=val;
           locked=true;
           }

         }
         void release()
         {
            Locked=false;
            value=0; 
          }
         void releasepair()
         {
            Paired=false;

         }

}
```